# azure functions return http response from a custom util function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Suppose I have an API for signup. I want to get data from the request and validate it in a Util function that I wrote and placed in another directory (see signup API and my Util directory in the picture). If validation goes fail, I want to return the HTTP response directly from that Util function. How can I achieve this?

[image: my project directory]

**In the **init**.py**

```
from utils.common_utils import validate
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    req_body = validate(req)
    
    # other stuff

    return func.HttpResponse("ok", status_code=200)
```

**and in my util function (validate function)**

```
def validate(input):
    if ...:
      return func.HttpResponse("check your input", status_code=406)
```

Comment: I don't think it can be implemented just by the code in `validate` function, do you mind add some code in main function ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I don't think it can return `HttpResponse` directly from that Util function and exit the main function. In your code, you can just return `HttpResponse` to `req_body` and then execute the following code of main function.

But I think if you write the code like below, it can also meet your requirement. It's the same thing.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    req_body = validate(req)

    if req_body.status_code == 406:
        return req_body

    return func.HttpResponse("ok", status_code=200)
```

Comment: It seems I don't have another option, so I keep forward like your way, thanks.

Comment: @MohammadGhorbani Thanks for your upvote, could you please also mark it as "accepted", thanks again.